# How to enforce number of lines entered in a ModelForm field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a modelform in which users can enter their bio. I don't want the bio to exceed 10 lines. I'm wondering where and how can I achieve this?

Here is the model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    username =  models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    bio=models.TextField(blank=True)
```

**Update:** 
Thanks to answer by electrometro, I added this validation method to the model:

```
def enforce_bio(self):
        bio = self.cleaned_data['bio']
        rows = bio.split('\n')
        if len(rows) > 10:
            raise forms.ValidationError("bio too long!")

        else:
            return bio
```

but it does not work as it should, that is, it allows bios longer than 10 lines. What is wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you want to limit lines? That's more like limiting paragraphs, because there will only be '\n' characters when people press Enter. Usually you limit either characters or words.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida, in this particular instance, yes, I'm sure that I want to limit lines delimited by `\n`.

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious, but since your included the model in your post... are you actually using the validator? Your model should have `bio=models.TextField(blank=True, validators=[enforce_bio])`. EDIT: And the validator takes the value of the field, not self.

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment. I misread your post, you don't seem to be using a validator at all. But then what _are_ you doing? You created the `enforce_bio` method in the model and you are using it how? The [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/) would be an easy solution.

Comment: apologies for my amateur mistakes. After adding `validators=[enforce_bio]` to the model field, I get this error `NameError: name 'enforce_bio' is not defined`, while the method is inside `UserProfile` class. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using a validator, put it in the beginning of the file, outside the class (or in a different file and import it).

Comment: Well, the django docs put the validatior inside model. When I put it above the class, `self` and `cleaned_data` are not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, for example:

```
def max_ten_lines(value):
    rows = value.split('\n')
    if len(rows) > 10:
        raise ValidationError("bio too long!")

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    username =  models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, validators=[max_ten_lines])
```

Comment: It works but I still want the data to be sanitized. Doesn't This method deprives the form applying `cleaned_data` check?

Comment: @Paulrx No, this works in addition to form cleaning. You could clean the field in the form too, but then you would have a `clean_bio` method in the form class.

Comment: Well, when lines excedes 10, this leads to `global name 'ValidationError' is not defined` at `if form.is_valid():`. how to fix this?

Comment: @Paulrx That's right at the top of the documentation I linked to, in the comments of the question. You need to import `ValidationError`.

Comment: Indead, it should be `from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError`. Thanks for bearing with me man!

Answer (score 2):

In your validation of your form you could easily split the text by the number the new line character and then just get the length of that list. Then if it is too long you can just send the form back as invalid by raising a `ValidationError` on the forms clean method.

The only problem with this is that it doesn't put that logic/validation check on the database. So you would need to do this everywhere the form is used.

For more information take a look at Django form validation [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/)

**Edit:**

To split the text into a list it would simply be `rows = text.split('\n')` and then to get the length of that list it would be `rows_length = len(rows)`. That would tell you how many lines the text is. You would have to do that inside your form validation.

Comment: Will you please elaborate on how to split the text and count the list?